# I want to move an arrow in javascript with mouse move

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Arrow move just fine. But the problem is when I change position of canvas in CSS, or include other elements in HTML it does not move properly. The arrow should point to where mouse pointer is. In this snippet it is working correctly after including HTML elements or applying CSS it does not moves to where mouse points.

```js
var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
cv.width = 1224;
cv.height = 768;
document.body.appendChild(cv);

var centerX = 600, centerY = 100;

var arrow = new Image();
arrow.onload = function() {
    drawArrow(0);
};
arrow.src = 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/35-200.png';

// NB: rotations go clockwise, and the Y axis goes down
function drawArrow(angle) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
    ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);   // correction for image starting position
  ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.drawImage(arrow, -arrow.width / 2, -arrow.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var dx = e.pageX - centerX;
  var dy = e.pageY - centerY;
  var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    drawArrow(theta);
};
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main{ 
  margin-top: 18%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;  
}
.work{ 
  margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: -18%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top:-1.5%;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.about{ 
  margin-left: -18%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top:-1.5%;
 
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 }
canvas{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="about">About</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't see what's wrong if you provide only the JS code. Please edit your question and create a code snippet (there's a "code snippet" button) so we can see the whole thing in action.

Comment: I have edited. Please check, here it functions properly because HTML and CSS is not applied after applying it ceases to work correctly.

Comment: Well, what you posted here works, so I'm not sure what there is to fix. All we know is that "when HTML is added" it "stops to work". Fixing is impossible if we have no clue about the problem :/

Comment: Please have a look now, now the problem should be clear. And sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is very clear now! I think I understand what's happening : CSS messes up everything. Like, when the canvas is full size (unconstrained), the arrow works. If the pointer is below it, the arrow will point directly down. Now, CSS resizes the whole canvas, makes it smaller and more to the left and down (because of margin-top). Suddenly, it looks like the arrow is wrong. It's still pointing down, but we're expecting it to point at the mouse cursor. So I understand what's happening, but unfortunately I couldn't find the fix :(

Comment: Ah that's bad, even without CSS, HTML messes it up. Not sure what this stingy problem might be.